# Difference between paginator and Symfony Profiler queries

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, symfony-3.3

I have a search page where I use a paginator. For a defined search, I don't have results (paginator->count = 0) but normally I must have some (for this search). So, I have looked at the Symfony profiler to see what is the query and to run it in phpmyadmin, to see what is the problem. 
But when I run the query get from the Symfony profiler ("runnable query"), I do have results in phpmyadmin.

This is the repo method :

```
public function findPaginated(Recherche $recherche = null)
    {
        if ($recherche != null)
        {
            $keywords = $recherche->getRecherche();
            $lieu = $recherche->getLieu();
            $categorie = $recherche->getCategorie();
            $max_results = $recherche->getNbResultats();
            $page = $recherche->getPage();
        }

        $queryString = 'SELECT a, c, u, au, aua, aa, p 
                        FROM AnnoncesBundle\Entity\Annonce a 
                        LEFT JOIN a.categorie c 
                        LEFT JOIN a.user u 
                        LEFT JOIN a.anonymousUser au 
                        LEFT JOIN au.adresse aua
                        LEFT JOIN u.adresse aa
                        LEFT JOIN a.photos p
                        WHERE 1=1';
        if ($categorie != null)
        {
            $queryString .= " AND a.categorie=:cat OR c.parent=:cat";
        }
        if ($keywords != null)
        {
            $queryString .= " AND MATCH (texte, titre) AGAINST (:keyword)";
        }
        if ($lieu != null && $lieu->getLieu() != null)
        {
            if ($lieu->getType() == 'region')
            {
                $queryString .= ' AND aua.postal LIKE ":departement%" OR aa.postal LIKE ":departement%" ';
            }
            else
            {
                if ($lieu->isLieuExact())
                {
                    if ($lieu->getType() == 'postcode')
                    {
                        $queryString .= " AND (aua.postal = :lieu OR aa.postal = :lieu) ";
                    }
                    elseif ($lieu->getType() == 'place')
                    {
                        $queryString .= " AND (aua.ville = :lieu OR aa.ville = :lieu) ";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $queryString .= " AND ((aua.lat >= :lat1 AND aua.lat <= :lat2 AND aua.lng >= :lng1 AND aua.lng <= :lng2) OR (aa.lat >= :lat1 AND aa.lat <= :lat2 AND aa.lng >= :lng1 AND aa.lng <= :lng2))";
                }
            }
        }

        $queryString .= " ORDER BY a.dateModification DESC";

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($queryString)
            ->setFirstResult(($page - 1) * $max_results)
            ->setMaxResults($max_results);

        if ($categorie != null)
        {
            $query->setParameter('cat', $categorie);
        }
        if ($keywords != null)
        {
            $query->setParameter('keyword', $keywords);
        }
        if ($lieu != null && $lieu->getLieu() != null)
        {
            if ($lieu->getType() == 'region')
            {
                $query->setParameter('departement', $lieu->getDepartement());
            }
            else
            {
                if ($lieu->isLieuExact())
                {
                    $query->setParameter('lieu', $lieu->getLieu());
                }
                else
                {
                    $bbox = $lieu->getBbox();
                    $query->setParameter('lng1', $bbox[0] - (1 / 77 * $lieu->getDistance()));
                    $query->setParameter('lat1', $bbox[1] - (1 / 111 * $lieu->getDistance()));
                    $query->setParameter('lng2',$bbox[2] + (1 / 77 * $lieu->getDistance()));
                    $query->setParameter('lat2', $bbox[3] + (1 / 111 * $lieu->getDistance()));
                }
            }
        }


        $pag = new Paginator($query);
        return $pag;
    }
```

The thing important to know is that with some other values, my search get the same nb of results than the profiler query, but not with this specified values (maybe with other values too...)

Any idea why I have this difference between my paginator result and the Symfony profiler query ?

Thanks !

Comment: Which paginator are you using? Pagerfanta, Knplabs, Doctrine, ... ? What is the FQCN of `Paginator`?

Comment: Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator

Comment: Did you debug the `$page` and `$max_results` variables? Are they correct?
 My first guess would be you get an empty result set because of a wrong offset or number of results:  `$query->setFirstResult(($page - 1) * $max_results)->setMaxResults($max_results);`.

Comment: I don't think so. With other values, my search get the same nb of results than the profiler query. But with this one, it is not the case... So the problem does not come from the $page or $max_results